# Vertically wrap around scroll in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a webpage which scrolls content, and when it reaches the bottom of the content continue to scroll the bottom off the page, while scrolling the top back on - so the bottom and the top will be on screen at the same time. Like the `<marquee>` tag, but vertically.

Only stuff I've managed to think up so far is (on load I use `setInterval()` to run this every 75ms)

```
function doScroll() {

window.scrollBy(0,1);

if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);   
}


}
```

Comment: have you actually tried something?  if so, please show us what you've tried.  if not, go try something before asking

Comment: keep yourself calm and try something :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm

Take a look at this. It has 'upward' in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS3, specially the property `marquee-direction`.

Together with `marquee-style`, `marquee-speed` and `marquee-play-count`, you can create the effect that you want.

See for example http://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_marquee-direction.cfm

Remember that HTML is semantic, but something moving isn't, so you should use CSS/JavaScript instead of `<marquee>`. Moreover, *this element was never added to the HTML specification and support for it varied widely across browsers* (http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3tutorials/a/marquee-in-css.htm)